# Sending email with file attachment using Google Cloud Function and Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, mailgun

I have a **Pub/Sub** topic where I publish messages and that pubsub topic is subscribed by a **Google Cloud Function** which sends the email to the customer using mailgun API.

This works fine so far, now I got the requirement that I have to send the email with the file **attachment**.

I can easily do this using Google Cloud Function using **HTTP** trigger but how to do it using a **Pub/Sub** topic?

Check the given image.

[image]

**Note:** The file size could be more than 10mb in my case.

Comment: Can you share your existing code ("I can easily do this using Google Cloud Function using HTTP trigger")?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It's here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if I understand your goal correctly, PubSub alone will never be enough as the actual work will happen at the function.

To achieve the above you need a cloud function [with Pub/Sub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub).

Once the function is called, you need to either fetch the attachment from a Google Cloud Bucket, or download it from a another API/source you have. You'll have to download it [inside the /tmp directory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) which is used to store temporary files.

Once completed, then you can use mailgun or other tools of your choice. Remember the attachment is inside the `/tmp` directory and not `./`

Using mailgun or any other method does not change anything on the overall approach. For example if you were to use Gmail API, you'd add [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) to your cloud function for the final step.